# ExtJS. Прикрепить handler к ссылкам по классу.

Tags: javascript, extjs

Есть группа ссылок, необходимо задать одинаковый обработчик с помощью ExtJS. У ссылок знаем классы. Например ссылка на удаление содержит в аттрибуте id номер записи, которую надо удалить. Хочу сначала обработать её с помощью ExtJS, а потом либо перейти по ссылке по дефолтному действию, либо это действие прекратить (аналог preventDefault() в jQuery).

В ExtJS нуб, погуглил не нашел. Помогите пожалуйста.

---

В общем хочу получить аналог такой функции jQuery:

```
$('.linkclass').click(function(e){    
    alert(this.attr('id'));    
    e.preventDefault();    
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Ext.select('.linkclass').on('click', function(e) {
    alert(e.target.id);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Хм... спасибо, действие прикрепилось. Но дефолтный переход по ссылке сохранился, тоесть e.preventDefault() не сработал... Как быть?